# Convert List of tuples to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Having a data as below:

```
mylist=[((10, 'L5', ['abc']), 0),
 ((15, 'L6', ['bda', 'LAS']), 5)]
```

I need to convert this data to data frame.  I need the dataframe/output as follows:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | L5 | ['abc'] | 0 |
| 15 | L6 | ['bda', 'LAS'] | 5 |

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: my_data = [((10, 'L5', ['abc']), 0), ((15, 'L6', ['bda', 'LAS']), 5)]
In [3]: new_my_data = [[col1, col2, col3, col4] for ((col1, col2, col3), col4) in my_data]
In [4]: new_my_data
Out[4]: [[10, 'L5', ['abc'], 0], [15, 'L6', ['bda', 'LAS'], 5]]
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(new_my_data, columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4'])
   ...: df
Out[5]: 
   COL1 COL2        COL3  COL4
0    10   L5       [abc]     0
1    15   L6  [bda, LAS]     5
```

Answer (score 1):

The data, in its current state, needs a little re-structuring to slot into a DataFrame nicely. To accomplish this, the dataset is iterated where each tuple and the additional value are concatenated into a single tuple. Finally, the list of concatenated tuples is slotted into the DataFrame as shown.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Original dataset.
data = [((10, 'L5', ['abc']), 0), 
        ((15, 'L6', ['bda', 'LAS']), 5)]

# Re-structure the data into a flattened list of tuples.
data_ = [a + (b, ) for a, b in data]
# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data_, columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4'])
```

Output:

```
   COL1 COL2        COL3  COL4
0    10   L5       [abc]     0
1    15   L6  [bda, LAS]     5
```